# Copiar y modificar un array en Java

Tags: java, objeto

Estoy intentando copiar un array (llamado arr[] y que pasa como parámetro) en otro nuevo (resultado[]) y modificar este segundo. Lo copio y modifico sin problema pero también me modifica el array original y eso no quiero que suceda.
Aquí dejo el código

```
public static Punto[] incremento(Punto arr[]) {
    Punto resultado[]= new Punto[arr.length];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++) {
        resultado[i]= arr[i];
        resultado[i].x += 1;
        
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Punto es un objeto

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te esta pasando es que le estas asignando el item del array1 al item del array2 para el no es una copia. Si no que a la que modificas un valor te lo modificara en el otro. ya que tu pregunta esta realizada para el lenguaje JAVA hay una funcion llamada **Arrays.copyof** te dejo un ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CopyArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

        int[] array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
           System.out.println("array2 position " + i + ": " + array2[i]);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Dónde puedo encontrar el código de esa función llamada Arrays.copyof?

Comment: tienes que importar primero el java.util.Arrays es una funcion propia del JAVA

Comment: Gracias. Eso lo he hecho y sí, ya funciona. Pero tenía curiosidad en ver el código de la función.

Comment: No podras es una funcion interna, las funciones internas no puedes ver el codigo...

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Gema cualquier código interno puedes ver en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) , si usar un IDE digamos netbeans, eclipse, etc, puedes navegar al código de cualquier método.